# Why did crawling errors regarding App Indexing increase instantly?

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-app-indexing

we experienced an instant app indexing error increase from 0 to more than 100k. We cannot explain the spontaneous increase of errors especially cause each error refers to the HTTP schema of deep links that we do not support at all.

We have established a custom schema which is successfully online since years now. Strange thing is also that despite the error reports, the search traffic seems to be okay. It has not dropped since, what we would have expected if there is a real problem.

What is even more confusing is that the deep links generated by the SearchConsoles help page are faulty. Regardless that they are generated with the HTTP schema the generated ADB command is correct but the generated intent URL for browsers is defininetly wrong.
 See this example for the site

http://www.finanzen.net/Kursziele/CEWE_Stiftung:

- `SearchConsole Help: intent://<OURPACKAGE>/http/www.finanzen.net/Kursziele/CEWE_Stiftung#Intent;scheme=android-app;package=undefined;end`
- `Firebase TestConsole Help: intent://www.finanzen.net/Kursziele/CEWE_Stiftung#Intent;scheme=http;package=<OURPACKAGE>;end`

So for the moment we suspect an update of SearchConsole to be responsible for this behaviour. If not we are completely puzzled.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Hi, we received the same GSC Message (just one message so far) and arehaving the exact same setup as yours.  No one seems to respond to the question on GWT Forum & here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283593/gsc-message-fix-deep-links-for-android-app-error-intent-uri-not-supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was seeing similar error reporting anomalies and reached out. I've heard from the App Indexing support team that this is a known issue and they are working on it. No ETA yet.

[Copy of email from App Indexing support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWOnF.png)