# GSC - Intent URI not supported -- Yes i didnt created the intent for that URL

Tags: android-intent, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

Today i had received 7000+ "Intent URI not supported" errors in GSC.

The issue is that i haven't mapped the google crawled web url in my app manifest file (as i do not have the corresponding page in app) NOR did i placed the link rel="alternate" tag on that web url page. Still google crawled and throws me this error.

What should i do to tell google that this pages are not be linked/indexed in the app.

And GSC tells that source of this crawling is "Source:  Google automated mapping". What does it mean ?

[image: GSC error]

Comment: Same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283593/gsc-message-fix-deep-links-for-android-app-error-intent-uri-not-supported I have not received a good answer for it yet.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Also on webmaster: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104282/sudden-spike-in-mobile-app-crawl-errors-search-console